# Massive performance improvement g++ 4.6 vs 4.7 vs 4.8 in aesni

Tags: assembly, g++, aes, compiler-optimization

I've been working for some time on a comparison between CPU AESNI and GPU AES. Recently i've updated the g++ compiler (from 4.6 to 4.8) and saw a significant increase in performance (~2x) for CPU AESNI.

I have a simplified C code to "simulate" AES encryption using AESNI instructions (listed bellow).

```
__m128i cipher_128i;
_ALIGNED(16) unsigned char in_alligned[16];
_ALIGNED(16) unsigned char out_alligned[16];

// store plaintext in cipher variable than encrypt
memcpy(in_alligned, buf_in, 16);
cipher_128i = _mm_load_si128((__m128i *) in_alligned);

cipher_128i = _mm_xor_si128(cipher_128i, key_exp_128i);
/* then do 9 rounds of aesenc, using the associated key parts */
cipher_128i = _mm_aesenc_si128(cipher_128i, key_exp_128i);
cipher_128i = _mm_aesenc_si128(cipher_128i, key_exp_128i);
cipher_128i = _mm_aesenc_si128(cipher_128i, key_exp_128i);
cipher_128i = _mm_aesenc_si128(cipher_128i, key_exp_128i);
cipher_128i = _mm_aesenc_si128(cipher_128i, key_exp_128i);
cipher_128i = _mm_aesenc_si128(cipher_128i, key_exp_128i);
cipher_128i = _mm_aesenc_si128(cipher_128i, key_exp_128i);
cipher_128i = _mm_aesenc_si128(cipher_128i, key_exp_128i);
cipher_128i = _mm_aesenc_si128(cipher_128i, key_exp_128i);
/* then 1 aesenclast rounds */
cipher_128i = _mm_aesenclast_si128(cipher_128i, key_exp_128i);

// store back from register & copy to destination
_mm_store_si128((__m128i *) out_alligned, cipher_128i);
memcpy(buf_out, out_alligned, 16);
```

This code on 1GB buf_in data on AMD 5400K (serial execution) yields the following:

- g++-4.6  | real 0m2.982s, user 0m2.466s, sys 0m0.433s
- g++-4.7  | real 0m1.453s, user 0m0.877s, sys 0m0.512s
- g++-4.8  | real 0m1.157s, user 0m0.592s, sys 0m0.468s

I generated assembly for each version of g++ (4.6, 4.7, 4.8) and found that the compiler was replacing sets of instructions of type **movdqa/movq** with **movdqu** (see picture bellow). 
http://postimg.org/image/q6j8qwyol/

Is it safe to assume this is the improvement ? Does it make sense ? Why did g++ 4.6 not consider this instruction in the first place ?

Comment: Improvements between subsequent compiler versions are quite normal. It may be that the compiler developers realised they could optimize based on aligned memory better between versions. Is it a problem that it's so much faster? Do your unit tests still pass?

Comment: It's a partial problem because i'll have to redo the cpu-gpu work split scenario having in mind that cpu now is 2x faster. I found the problem was because of the compiler update, after initially checking everything else - I initially thought i made a mistake somewhere - (work distribution error, measurement error etc). I want to pinpoint the optimization since i want to give an explanation for the change and not invalidate all my previous measurements.

Comment: It looks to me like `memcpy` improved.  Previous versions (by looking at the assembly you posted) used movdqa which required alignment so it had to add extra code to ensure alignment.  In 4.8 it simply does movdqu which does not require alignment.  On Systems since Sandy Bridge unaligned loads/stores are not really different in speed than aligned ones.  If you don't mind the errors you could comment out the `memcpy` functions and see what the performance is.

Comment: Since you're only copying 16 bytes you could make your own memcpy function with _mm_loadu_si128 and _mm_storeu_si128.

Comment: I've tried running the code on AMD Kabini and there seems to be no performance difference in the generated binaries from g++ 4.6 to 4.8. The problem looks indeed to be related to memcpy improvement - why such a radical difference between compilers though ? It may be indeed that unaligned is today no different than aligned and the g++ 4.6/4.7 compiler had a problem that generated non-optimal code (even with O3 !!!). I will try some more experiments and will post updates on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

3 things I noticed affecting performance between the 3:

1) Better copying of data. In the old GCC, it appears to be breaking up the 16B copies into 2 8B loads/stores. This is probably because the unaligned instructions used to be terrible for performance (they were micro coded) on older architectures. After Intel's Nehalem processor, the unaligned instructions were made just as fast as the aligned instructions, assuming no cache splits. Compilers, therefore, try to take advantage of this by being more liberal in their use of unaligned instructions.

2) Looks like GCC optimized away a buffer overrun check, which contributed to some overhead. Haven't looked into detail why.

3) Also looks like they optimized away the need to dynamically aligned the stack pointer to 32B (needed in the first case so that we could use movdqa, not needed in the second case, therefore, probably a perf-bug, and optimized away in the third case).